# Unable install aptdaemon-data package now

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 a month ago and the process showed a few errors but ultimately completed. But since then I've been unable to run sudo apt upgrade. It'd ive errors about being unable to make a backup link of some icon.

Everytime I try sudo apt upgrade it showed an error similar to this one just below. (I am unable to reproduce the exact error because I tried removing and reinstalling the aptdaemon-data package)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptdaemon-data
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/159 kB of archives.
After this operation, 254 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 366121 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../aptdaemon-data_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu39_all.deb ...
Unpacking aptdaemon-data (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu39) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/aptdaemon-data_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu39_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/aptdaemon-data_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu39_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried checking for flags and this is what it shows

```
ls -ll /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 8296 1870 Nov  6  1927 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png
```

Nevertheless I tried running chattr but it doesn't work either

```
sudo chattr -ia /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png
chattr: Operation not supported while setting flags on /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png
```

I unmounted and booted from a livecd and ran fsck which didn't show any errors either.

I tried being root as `sudo su` and running the apt upgrade command there and that brought up the same error.

I tried removing the aptdaemon-data package which worked and but then I've been unable to install it again. I tried `sudo apt upgrade` and that showed some packages as being held back. I ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and which installed those packages. And now apt says my system is up to date.

Now when I try to install the aptdaemon-data package, apt shows the above error `unable to make backup link of './usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png' before installing new version: Operation not permitted`

At this point I am not sure what to do and I don't know if this aptdaemon-data package is important or if I can continue without it. I don't know if this will affect future updates. Any inputs on this, or on how to fix that error is appreciated.

It just feels wrong to me that there's a file in the icons dir which cannot be removed or edited in any way, even when I am being root.

EDIT

Running `lsattr /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png` gives

```
lsattr /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png
-u---a-Ac---tTe------m /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png
```

And running `ls -al /usr/share/icons/hicolor/` gives

```
total 208
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root  4096 Jun 28 07:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root  4096 Jun 24 23:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun 10 17:18 100x100
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  8  2021 1024x1024
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 128x128
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 30  2021 150x150
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 30  2021 160x160
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Jun 10 17:01 16x16
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 192x192
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  8  2021 20x20
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Jun 10 17:01 22x22
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Nov  4  2021 24x24
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 256x256
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  8  2021 28x28
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 30  2021 30x30
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Jun 10 17:01 32x32
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 36x36
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  8  2021 40x40
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 26  2021 42x42
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun  8  2021 480x480
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Nov  4  2021 48x48
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 30  2021 50x50
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 512x512
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 64x64
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 72x72
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 26  2021 8x8
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 20  2021 96x96
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 34992 Jun 28 07:55 icon-theme.cache
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55507 Mar 19  2018 index.theme
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Apr 25  2021 scalable
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jun 10 17:01 symbolic
```

Comment: Mv the file to your home and try again

Comment: @nobody Tried that as sudo, says Operation not permitted. Similarly unable to remove the file also.

Comment: can you add `lsattr /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png` and `ls -al /usr/share/icons/hicolor/`

Comment: @nobody I've added the output of those to the original question

Comment: `sudo -s` after that you are root. you can control it with `whoami`  now try with `chattr -a /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png` to remove the append flag. then try to erase it as root.

Comment: After `sudo -s` `whoami` says root, but chattar says `chattr: Operation not supported while setting flags on /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/status/aptdaemon-cleanup.png`

Comment: this is tenacious. have you tried a filesystemcheck? What is your filesystem?  `sudo lsblk -f` will show it.

Answer (score 0):

That´s rare. umm. Did u tried first `sudo apt-get install -f` and the `sudo apt update`  again, and `sudo apt upgrade` to `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
Or download the .deb file. The aptdaemon .deb
See what happens!

Comment: Tried the ```sudo apt-get install -f```` and the rest of those commands. It doesn't show any problems at all. Says all packages are up to date. Until I tried running dist-upgrade a few days back, the aptdaemon-data package was an item in the list of packages to be updated and apt was trying to update it which fails and the rest of the packages won't get updated either. But after the dist-upgrade again, now apt doesn't want to upgrade it anymore. But those icon files are still left there.